# UISearchDisplayController Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to implement UISearchDisplayController in my existing tableview but whenever i try to search it covers all the view. Please check the below screen shot more detail idea.

I am using xCode 7 Beta and iOS9 Simulator.

[image]
[image]

Here when i start searching it covers all the screen.

[image]

I already search for this but none of the solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried a similar test project on Xcode 7 without auto layout and it works fine for me:
[image]
[image]

What exactly does your view hierarchy look like? Perhaps the top bar on your view is preventing the search bar from moving up?

Comment: well my app is compatible for iOS 7 also so I guess i have to go with UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController

Comment: OK. Can you post screenshots of how your storyboard is set up (eg autolayout constraints) and what you have implemented in terms of UISearchDisplayDelegate?

Comment: I am using AutoResizing not autolayout. I have just drag and drop uisearchdisplay controller in my tableview of uiviewcontroller and implement one delegate method of uiseach to filter data

Comment: Have updated the original answer - can you share what your view hierarchy looks like on the storyboard?